# memchr returns unexpected characters

Tags: c

I'm trying my best to understand the memchr function but having some issues with some simple output. I'm getting extra characters at the end of *newchar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char plus[6] = "12+123";    
    char *newchar = (char*) memchr(plus,43,3);
    printf("%s",newchar);
}
```

output:

```
+123( '
```

I expected to get "+123," why does it give me the extra characters? I noticed the output is consistent which confuses me earlier, it doesn't seem like these were grabbed from somewhere random in memory but were caused by the memchr function.

Comment: Remember that strings in C are really call ***null terminated*** strings.

Comment: You do not need the cast

Comment: Why are you using `43` instead of `'+'`?

Comment: Don't rely on the character being found: check the return value from `memchr` which is `NULL` if not found.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! Write **readable and understandable** code!

Comment: Read about C strings and the null-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

```
char plus[6] = "12+123";
```

You've defined an array of size 6, and initialized it with 6 characters. You haven't left enough room for the NUL terminator. There is garbage at the end of your string, and `printf` doesn't know when to stop printing it.

Do this instead, allowing the string to be appropriately sized automatically:

```
 char plus[] = "12+123";
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Normally I agree. In this case however, it is much more than a simple typographical error. It turns out that fixing a fundamental misunderstanding required only a single character change.

Comment: Posters are required to know the language basics. The convention for C "strings" are one of those fundamentals. Removing the `6` or adding `1` can be considered a typo. (not that the commitee did any good not making  such an legacy initialiser illegal with C11).